# How organize this data in a respective column

Tags: excel, pandas, numpy, csv

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: can you guys tell me please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BPZ9.jpg

Comment: `read_csv` SO post data as text not images,  can't provide solution from images

Comment: https://olympus.greatlearning.in/courses/11267/files/780719?module_item_id=479727

Comment: https://olympus.greatlearning.in/courses/11267/files/780719?module_item_id=479727         you can download csv file from this link...

Answer (score 0):

oFile.csv data sample

```
store_id,city,v,Jan,Feb
S_1,Texas,8,20,13
S_2,California,12,19,15
```

store it as a oFile.csv. I see pandas tag

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('oFile.csv')
```

Comment: OFile. Csv? What does that mean?

Comment: Can you show me screenshot of that one  , ofile. Csv

Comment: Store your content as a csv file 'oFile.csv'.I will post the data in next comment that i stored.

Comment: I doesn't work i have already tried by storing data as u mentioned